# Is there a way (stock or customization) to highlight multiple instances of variables within an R script

Tags: r, rstudio

So as the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to syntactically (or through diagnostics) highlight when either multiple instances of a variable exist or when there are multiple assignments being made to the same variable name.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://community.rstudio.com/t/highlight-same-variable-in-color/29936/3

Comment: @r2evans Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. It would need to be constantly checking the script and making the syntactic highlights, which is why I brought the diagnostics bit into the question.

Comment: I understand. Many of the syntactic checks I'm aware of are things like `R CMD check` that looks for references to uninitialized variables; if that's what you wanted, then re-using that might work. But it's not, so ... I suspect you'd need to look at how [`lintr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lintr/index.html) does what it does and try to extend it.